# Qt Websocket ssl peerAddress

Tags: qt, ssl, websocket, wss

I am working on an application, where i manage multiple websocket connections with an interface to connect single connections with each other. Lets call it a chat. The application works well with NonSecureMode Websockets, but when i use  QWebSocketServer::SecureMode i run into a problem.

I use a wrapper class for each client, which saves the IP,Port and pointer to the websocket object. When looking through my lists of connected chat partners, i use the ip:port combination to search for. When using SecureMode, the websocket will not return any ip address.

```
    qDebug() << "Client connected:" << pSocket->peerAddress().toString() << pSocket->peerPort();
```

Returns the following debug statement:

> Client connected: "::1" 2058

Is there any way to access the ip with SecureConnections on Websockets? The SSL Layer should be way above the IP and TCP Layer, so the information should still be available somehow. The websocket API did show any options to get the ip address.

Comment: That is a valid IP. That is IPv6 localhost. Are you testing locally?

Comment: Yes, i am currently working locally. I will execute the connection scripts on another system and test it further. This could make some sense if it is just the local IPv6 address, but it still baffles me, that it changes behaviour on changing to SSL Sockets like this.

Comment: Well, it all depends on which options are used when creating the socket, or if. e.g. happy eyeballs is being implemented and so forth... it might just work with v4 as expected when you run it on the public Internet.

Comment: Had to work on a different task for a while, but i thought about the matter and found, that each connecting socket will have its own port on the server side. This should be sufficient as the primary key to find socket connections.